# unable to write to socket [1]: Operation not permitted in web server but working ok on localhost why?

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, webserver, time-and-attendance

I am trying to connect to a attendance device on ethernet by ip address and get data from it. I am working with zklib library for this. Problem is it is working ok in localhost but when I am trying on web server it is showing

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: socket_sendto(): unable to write to socket [1]: Operation not 
permitted

Filename: zklib/zkconnect.php

Line Number: 11

Backtrace:
```

cant i get data from a attendance device on webserver by this zklibrary or problem is something else !

;extension=php_sockets.dll was disable but after enable showing same message why .
I have a real ip for the attendance device to access.

Please if anyone have any idea !
Thank's in advanced !

Comment: Go ahead and look for an entry called `disable_functions`. It might be possible the function is deactivated.

Comment: @TobiasF. there is no value for disable_functions in phpinfo

Comment: @M.Alim I'm having exactly the same problem. Have you solved this?

Comment: i am sorry my friend i was unable to solve it !